# How do I parse comma separated data in raptor?

Tags: raptor

I'm trying to input data from a csv file into a raptor program. I am not allowed to edit the csv file. The file contains names and sales in the format, "name,sales". I need the data to be entered into either 2 different arrays or a 2D array.  However, raptor takes each line as one individual input.  How do I separate the data from each line into the two arrays?

I've looked everywhere on google. I think maybe I could read the data into one big array and then try to split the array? I just don't know how I would split each element of the array.

Here is a screenshot of the csv file: